# How to add an object or key value pair to MultipartFormDataContent then send it and receive it on the API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am sending an image to the API using `MultipartFormDataContent` and i can grab the image using `var file = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;` without a problem. How can I send additional data like an array or object together with the image and then grab it on the other end of the API? I tried using Key value pairs but with no luck getting it on the API. Below is how i am adding using key value pair but i have no idea how i can receive this data on the API:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
    using (var content = new MultipartFormDataContent())
    {
        var fileStream = new FileStream(tempFilePath, FileMode.Open);
        formData.Add(new StreamContent(fileStream), fileName, fileName);
        //Below am sending the name from the object lblobj and giving it a key of name
        formData.Add(new StringContent(lblobj.Name), "name");
        streams.Add(fileStream);

        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, new Uri(_configuration["Application:ApiEndPoint"]) + "api/Label/Create")
        {
            Content = formData,
        };

        request.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        streams.ForEach(stream =>
        {
            stream.Dispose();
        });

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            //Handle success
        }
        //handle failure

    }
}
```

Below is how i receive the file on the API:

```
 var image = HttpContext.Request.Form.Files;
//Deal with the image(iformfile)
```

How can i receive the additional data above?

Comment: A html message contains headers and a body (with optional attachments).  So there are a few ways of sending multiple data 1) Use GZIP to combine data into one Base64 string 2) Add data as Http Headers 2) Create a multipart message (MIME).  Each part is separated by a new line starting with two dashes.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140)?force_isolation=true

Comment: Let me look into this. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here's my test result:

[image]

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;

private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

public HomeController( IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
{
    _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
}

[HttpPost]
public async Task receiveDataAsync(ApiModel model) {
    var name = model.fileName;
    var file = model.image;
    if (file != null)
    {
        string uploadsPath = Path.Combine(_hostingEnvironment.WebRootPath, "css");
        string uniqueName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + "_" + name+".png";
        string filePath = Path.Combine(uploadsPath, uniqueName);
        using (Stream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

And this is the model, and I also think you need to create a model for your api:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace WebMvcApp.Models
{
    public class ApiModel
    {
        public string fileName { get; set; }
        public IFormFile image { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a model and the model is bringing in data like the image itself, name and other values so the problem now is sending those extra values to my API. I am able to send the image itself and grab it but the problem is the extra details and how i can add them to the SendAsync

Comment: Could you please check my screenshot and show me what kind of data you want to send to the api?

Comment: I wanted to send strings as key value pairs since i cant send an entire object or a list. I managed to append the strings and then on the API all i did was use the model to bind the data. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I appended the strings from my object in key value pairs like below

```
   formData.Add(new StringContent(lblobj.PageColor), "pageColor");
   formData.Add(new StringContent(lblobj.Name), "name");                       
   formData.Add(new StringContent(lblobj.SidebarColor), "sidebarColor");
   formData.Add(new StringContent(lblobj.SidebarLinkColor), "sidebarLinkColor");
```

On the API end point all i did was append these to a model containing all those keys like below;

```
 public IActionResult Create([FromForm] Label labelobj)
{

//Do something with the values }
```

The labelobj contains pageColor etc